# Spring mongoDB xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot

May you could say why here is error when I try to configurate spring mongoDB xml(config) file. (Error in description bellow)

[image]

Comment: Please attach configuration and error message. No images please.

Answer (score 0):

This configrution based on my project.you can modify it your according

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd"
default-autowire="byName">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.soe.mongo" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:soe-mongodao.properties" />

<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="#{mongoURI.username}" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="#{new java.lang.String(mongoURI.password)}" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI" id="mongoURI">
    <constructor-arg value="${soe.db.spring.data.mongo.url}"  />
</bean>

<bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoURI" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${soe.db.spring.data.mongodb.database}" />
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
</bean>
<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in 
    @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in context XML and add it to the classpath. Add corresponding properties in your properties file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <mongo:mongo host="${dataSource.mongo.host}" 
      port="${dataSource.mongo.port}"
  </mongo:mongo>

  <mongo:db-factory dbname="${dataSource.mongo.databaseName}" mongo-
      ref="mongo" username="${dataSource.mongo.username}" 
      password="${dataSource.mongo.password}" />

  <bean id="mongoTemplate" 
     class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
  </bean>
```